# How to remove the bottom 1px of an inline-block (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I will refer to this screenshot in my explanation:

[image: Screenshot]

I have set up tabs like you see in the picture. I wanted the active tab (home in the picture) to have a 1px black line under it, so I used bottom-border. However, it's difficult to see but the pink-ish background extends for that entire row. I would like the pink to stop drawing at the bottom of a tab, excluding a border if there is one (so just 1px above the bottom).

```
.main_tabs{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FFDEFD;
}

li.active a, li.active{ 
    background:#fff;
    color:#4c4c4c;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    transition:all linear 0.4s;
}
```

Above is my CSS for main_tabs (which is responsible for that pink background) and the active tab. In main_tabs, I have tried playing around with background-size but it didn't change anything. I tried to fiddle with width and display, but it messed up my tabs entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.main_tabs {
  background: #FFDEFD;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .25em .5em 0;
}

.main_tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main_tabs a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  background: #DDD;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: all linear 0.4s;
}

.main_tabs .active a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class=main_tabs>
  <li><a href=#>Non active</a></li>
  <li class=active><a>Active</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your border is added in original height of `<li>` that why it appears like this.

Use css property `box-sizing:border-box` to merge it in original height.

```
li.active a, li.active{ 
    background:#fff;
    color:#4c4c4c;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    transition:all linear 0.4s;
}
```

Comment: I added -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; where you suggested, but nothing changed. I then tried adding it to the * {}, but still nothing changed. The reference for box-sizing:border-box appears to be what I need, so is there a small thing I'm forgetting to do?

Comment: i don't think there is anything wrong provided code...could you please create a fiddle to show me your problem

Comment: @Yifan, `box-sizing` won't affect the result if height is not explicitly specified.

Comment: Anyway, it's a bad way because of many reasons. 1. If you have height with box-sizing, you need to compensate content-box sizes difference by padding to make baseline the same. 2. You just don't need height for this.

Comment: agree with you...ur answer is more simple...upvoting

Comment: @Qwertiy I used your example and it worked. Thanks! Sorry I'm going to be a little picky now, so only answer if it's a quick change (sorry I'm new to this but I'm fairly certain these aren't easy changes). 1. Is there a way to have that bottom line look like it's off the tab like if you took the pink out of my earlier picture? 2. The text is centred in the tab, but with the addition of the border like this, it doesn't look centred anymore. Is there a way to visually centre it again?

Comment: @Yifan 1. `margin-bottom: -1px`. 2. The text is centered.

Comment: Alright, that worked. I had to change one other thing though. Instead of the non-active tab border being transparent, I made it white like the background at that part. Now it looks exactly as I wanted it https://gyazo.com/28800c0034995af523025ab5ff163aa3. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Yifan, you could've use `background-clip: padding-box;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip